# How do you stop ReadOnly columns from disappearing when editing/updating a GridView in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to create a GridView to display the contents of a table on my database. I want the user to be able to edit only one of the columns, so I set every other one to read only. When I test this, I can only edit the one column, like intended, but after updating, the other columns become null and post to the database. I don't know how to stop this from happening. Here is my code for the GridView. It is bound with one of Visual Studio's SQLDataSources.

I tried to create several events including RowEditing, RowUpdated, and RowUpdating, but with no luck. Nothing would stop the non-edited fields from getting replaced with NULL.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  Align="center" Height="138px" Width="548px" BorderColor="#6600FF" BorderStyle="Ridge" HorizontalAlign="Center" DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" Visible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PhoneName" HeaderText="PhoneName" SortExpression="PhoneName" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Amount" HeaderText="Amount" SortExpression="Amount" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Price" HeaderText="Price" SortExpression="Price" ReadOnly="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalPrice" HeaderText="TotalPrice" SortExpression="TotalPrice" ReadOnly="True" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Edit: I found a working solution by changing the SQLDataSource's Update Query String to set the unchangeable categories to their original values and leaving the one changeable field to a parameter. I'll post the code for that here.

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="*connection string here*" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Cart]" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Cart] WHERE [Id] = @original_Id" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Cart] ([PhoneName], [Amount], [Price], [TotalPrice]) VALUES (@PhoneName, @Amount, @Price, @TotalPrice)" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Cart] SET [PhoneName] = PhoneName, [Amount] = @Amount, [Price] = Price, [TotalPrice] = TotalPrice WHERE [Id] = @original_Id" DataSourceMode="DataReader">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </DeleteParameters>
            <InsertParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TotalPrice" Type="String" />
            </InsertParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="PhoneName" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Amount" Type="Int32" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="Price" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="TotalPrice" Type="String" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_Id" Type="Int32" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Can you post your code for your datasource named "SqlDataSource1"? Is this how you are doing your update command? If you are doing the update from codebehind, then that information would be helpful also.

Comment: I managed to find the answer to my own question thanks to this comment. What I needed to do was change the Update Query string on the SQLDataSource's line of code. I'll post it here anyway in case there is a better solution, but thank you for responding

Comment: yeah i suspected that was the issue. glad you were able to find the answer